# would unnecessary header files effect anything

Tags: c, header-files

I have a long C code that is written for Linux environment. I have been adding and removing standard functions, so that I have been adding new headers, but never go through the code to find out if there is any unnecessary headers.

I wonder having unnecessary headers on the code would effect anything? If it does not effect anything, why C does not include all standard libraries by default?

Comment: It has an impact on the amount of time spent pre-processing.  It is usually negligible.  It was often not neglible 25 years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unnecessary headers mostly affect compilation speeds, because of how stupid C's inclusion mechanism is: the entire header is read in and copy-pasted in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), will save you the trouble of worrying if you've already defined something.

It also prevents double inclusion where something is included twice and causes compilation errors.

Comment: I think he meant if he includes a header file that he doesn't need, not a header file that has already been included...I agree though, use include guards for sure